# Mouse Hover on Slider not working to show another image

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, slider

I'm having some problem with the slider. I have using this slider on WordPress page with custom plugin that allow to add html/css/js after an update I have lost a script so I can't find.
The problem is this normally is an image without color, but on hover I want to show the original image with color, pagination is working well, so next image need to be shown without color. I will share the code that I have with missing js for hover to show other image.

As you can see I have 2 links

```
<img src="https://www.pika.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_1_1-1.jpg" />
first line for slider that is normally shown
<img src="https://www.pika.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_1_2-1.jpg" />
second line for the slider that need to be shown only on mouse hover
```

---

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  //                autoplay: {
  //                    delay: 2500,
  //                    disableOnInteraction: false
  //                },
  autoplay: false,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
  }
});
$(".swiper-container").mouseenter(function() {
  swiper.autoplay.start();
});
$(".swiper-container").mouseleave(function() {
  swiper.autoplay.stop();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.5/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.5/css/swiper.css" />
<div class="slider-comp core-slider">
  <div class="core-slider__info">
    <div class="core-slider__arrows">
      <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="core-slider__images">
    <div class="custom-swiper swiper-container">
      <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="aspect-ratio">
            <img src="https://www.pika.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_1_1-1.jpg" />
            <img src="https://www.pika.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_1_2-1.jpg" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="aspect-ratio">
            <img src="https://www.pika.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_2_1-1.jpg" />
            <img src="https://www.pika.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_2_2-1.jpg" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="aspect-ratio">
            <img src="https://www.pika.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_3_1-1.jpg" />
            <img src="https://www.pika.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_3_2-1.jpg" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="aspect-ratio">
            <img src="https://www.pika.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_4_1-1.jpg" />
            <img src="https://www.pika.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_4_2-1.jpg" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- If we need pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class to the img-tags and add the styles for the hover-effect. Hide the hover image as default. If you hover on the div around the images, hide the default image and show the other one.

```css
.hover_img{display: none;}
.aspect-ratio:hover .hover_img{
  display: block;
}
.aspect-ratio:hover .standard_img{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="aspect-ratio">
            <img class="standard_img" src="https://www.pika.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_1_1-1.jpg" />
            <img class="hover_img" src="https://www.pika.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/slider_1_2-1.jpg" />
            </div>
```

You could also place the hover-image absolute above the standard image and add some effects.